# C++11 Deferred function calling

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I create event manager for game engine.
And I have some problem with it.

Now, my programm can do smth like this:

```
RegCallback(E_EVSYS_MSG::MATHSQRT, &test_it, &test::bar, 10, 100.0);
RegCallback(E_EVSYS_MSG::MATHSQRT, &SomeCallback, 10.0f, 100);

CallEvent(E_EVSYS_MSG::MATHSQRT);
```

But, it's not right.
I store function with paramaters in std::bind:

```
std::function< void() > m_Func;
m_Func = std::bind(pmfn, ref, std::forward<ARGS>(data)...);
```

---

So... I don't know, how to separate storing function ptr and parameters.

It have to work like this:

```
RegCallback(E_EVSYS_MSG::MATHSQRT, &test_it, &test::bar);
RegCallback(E_EVSYS_MSG::MATHSQRT, &SomeCallback);

CallEvent(E_EVSYS_MSG::MATHSQRT, 10, 100.0);
```

How to achieve this??
std::bind returns templated std::function, and this is very hard to save it in vector.
Basically, all callbacks difference only in ptr to function(its may be method or order function). And all callbacks have same parameters(but not same data in paramaters).

P.S Full code of test programm: http://pastebin.com/Rdyy5LGU

Comment: `std::vector< std::function< void() > >` is perfectly fine. For something more elaborate, check [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2.html)

Comment: _"all callbacks have same parameters"_ That is exactly what `std::function` is for.

Comment: No! I can't store std::function in std::vector!!

Comment: Yes you can. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: No.. all callbacks in one message have the same parameters. But other message have a group of another callbacks with another parameters. i.e. MATHSQRT with (int, double), INIT with (string, float), etc...

Comment: AFAIK its not possible to create a `std::vector` that can store multiple versions of `std::function` i.e. `void(int, double)` as well as `void(string, float)`.